# Bounds for $I(c)=\int_{c+ia}^{c+ib}e^{-z^2}\,dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to make sure I properly established that this goes to $0$.

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$, and let $I(c)$ be defined for $c\in \mathbb{R}$ as $I(c)=\int_{c+ia}^{c+ib}e^{-z^2}.$  Find an upper bound for $|I(c)|$ and conclude that $I(c)\to 0$ as $c\to \pm \infty$.

I'm stuck trying to derive the upper bound.

$$|I(c)|=\left|\int_{a}^{b}e^{-(c+it)^2}\,dz\right|\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left|e^{-(c+it)^2}\right|\,\left|dz\right|$$

I believe expanding the stuff in the exponent gives us $e^{t^2-c^2}e^{-2ict}=e^{t^2-c^2}[\cos{2c\theta}+i\sin{2c\theta}].$  This means

$$\left|I(c)\right|\leq exp^{t^2-c^2}=\frac{e^{t^2}}{e^{c^2}} $$

The last inequality goes to 0 as $c \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first inequality is correct.  You then have

$$|I(c)| \le e^{-c^2} \int_a^b dt \, e^{t^2} dt \le e^{-c^2} e^{b^2} (b-a)$$

which vanishes as $c\to\infty$.

Comment: What about for $c \to -\infty$?

Comment: @EugeneTooms: I think that is self-apparent, no?

Comment: As I think about it more, I don't know why I remarked on it.